# Are the free online packs able to be reaquired on consecutive playthroughs?

Tags: yakuza-0

I got the free packs from Bob at the shrine but he says they are one-time use. Do they come back on another playthrough or is it one-time use and only on one playthrough?

Answer (score 1):

Bob Uzunomiya 0's packs are all on a per-save basis and free to acquire again on any new playthrough. You still can only get one of each pack in a playthrough, however.